# ModelForm: display foreign key field

Tags: django-forms

considering the following code:

models.py

```
class Manufacturers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Cars(models.Model):
    producedby = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturers)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateCar(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Cars
```

... on the html page the "producedby" field appears like a list of "Manufacturer object" choices, which is not very useful, is it possible to display the Manufacturer.name field instead?
I have tried solutions suggested in other threads but none of them worked.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by overloading the __str__ method and returning the name as follows:

```
class Manufacturers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    def __str__(self): return self.name
```

Comment: Don't you still get the choices dropdown? How do you just display the value?

Answer (score 0):

This may a little late, but for future reference, I would fix it by changing my template file to:

```
car_details.html

{{ CreateCarForm.instance.producedby.name }}
```