# Displaying foreign key attributes in ModelForm Django

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Form:

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'parent']
```

When I view the form's 'parent' dropdown, I get a list of objects:

- Company object
- Company object
- Company object
- Company object

I want to display the objects' names in the dropdown instead:

- unilever
- general mills
- kraft
- yoplait

What lines of code do I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `__unicode__` legacy method, or if you are up to date, you'll implement the `__str__` method, decorating the class as python2compatible [seen in the django 1.11 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods):

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

In 2019, you'll probably/hopefully start your project in python3, and will be able to omit all the python 2/3 compatibility things.

Answer (score 1):

This was handled a bit differently [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587229/modelform-display-foreign-key-field). Here they set the **str** property of the class to the the value of the field they wanted to show. Not sure if there are side effects of this, though.